# cvim commands don't work from command mode, but work from the GUI menu

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I've used vi/vim for editing files and am comfortable with the basics of entering insert mode (pressing "a" key) and using ESC to get into control mode to write the file and exit.

I'm following the `cvim` tutorial [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/01/tutorial-make-vim-as-your-cc-ide-using-cvim-plugin/), except I'm using vim-gtk on Ubuntu 12.04. Commands like ^Wv (Left Ctrl + W, then v) work correctly (split window down the middle), but when I go into command mode (press ESC) and do (\ is backslash character):

```
\if
```

It automatically puts me in insert mode. However, I can run the command from the GUI menu and it works fine (creating a C++ function in this case).

Am I missing something fundamental here? Is a backslash not a backslash? I cannot find any documentation anywhere on Google about this.

I'd be grateful if someone could point out where I'm going wrong. GVIM works fine from the menu, but it would be more productive to be able to use the commands within the editor.

Thanks in advance for any help/tips/pointers :-)

Comment: Just to check: did you type the whole thing [quite quickly](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40932/22651)?

Comment: I've typed as fast as I can. As soon as I hit the i in \if it goes into insert mode. Even a command like \pd returns nothing, yet it works (and brings up a mini dialogue) when called using GUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file must be saved as a valid C/C++ file before it will work. Thanks ire_and_curses for the resource